# WPF MVVM: I have a custom usercontrol, get that value and set another in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am accessing MyCustomControl X value to be the default value in the Textbox.

I used to have this in xaml

```
 <TextBox x:Name="NumX" Text="{Binding Y}" />
```

Y gets the value in NumX. However, now I want to default the value of Y to what is referenced in MyCustomControl.

Now I change to :

```
 <TextBox x:Name="NumX" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyCustomControl, Path=X}" />
```

How do I update the Y property value to be the value in NumX? This currently makes Y value null because it is never set.  I looked at triggers and multibinding but it doesn't make sense to me they are the correct way to follow.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a Dependency Property on your MyCustomControl; this exposes the property and will allow your to bind your ViewModel property to it.

So if you add a YProp dependency property to your MyCustomControl, you can do something like this, assuming your ViewModel is the DataContext of your custom control and you have a matching property `Y` in the ViewModel:

```
<local:MyCustomControl YProp="{Binding Y}" />
```

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. Y is not a value in MyCustomControl.

Comment: Have you looked at dependency properties? Why would you use Path=X when you want Y? Maybe provide an image of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I used dependency properties to get the value of X in MyCustomControl. I want the property Y to be set to Path=X because Y value need to be referenced in the ViewModel. The default value of X may be 35 degree C but Y will look at that value and change it to F, for example.

Comment: There's may be more to dependency properties I haven't thought about. I would appreciate any reference you may thinking of.

Comment: @kay00 When I was learning dependency properties I used [Jeff Wilcox's Silverlight snippets](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/silverlight-snippets/). Even though it says Sivlerlight I have used them on WP8 and WPF. Usage of them help eases the pain of creating them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it at the code behind. Creating a custom control and setting up MVVM made this problem not easily solvable.